# Sql rank by most matches

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for some help to rank record by most matches. 
Let’s say I have skill table like this.

```
Employeeid.    Skillid.   Skill
1.              1.         Java
1.              2.         C#
1.              3.         F#
1.              4.         MVC
2.              1.         Java
2.              4.          F#
3.              3.          Mvc
3.              1.          Java
3.              4.          Mvc
4.              5.          Ms Word
```

Skill to match ['java', 'c#', 'F#', 'MVC']

Output show be like below because employee 1 matches all skills followed by employee 2 then 3.

```
Employeeid.     Rank
1.                1
3.                2
2.                3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about including just the matched skills?  This would look like:

```
select employeeid, count(*) as matching_skills
from t
where skill in ('java', 'c#', 'F#', 'MVC')
order by count(*) desc;
```

If you really need a number, you can use either `row_number()`/`dense_rank()` (MySQL 8+) or variables.

Answer (score 0):

- In a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), firstly get employee id and its skill count, sorted by the [count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html) in Descending order.
- Now, we can use [user-defined Session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), to compute the Rank.

Try the following:

```
SELECT dt.employeeid,
       CASE
         WHEN @prev_count <> dt.total_skills THEN @rank := @rank + 1
         ELSE @rank
       end                            AS Rank,
       @prev_count := dt.total_skills AS Total_skills
FROM   (SELECT t1.employeeid,
               Count(DISTINCT t1.skillid) AS total_skills
        FROM   your_table_name AS t1
        WHERE  t1.skill IN ( 'Java', 'C#', 'F#', 'MVC' )
        GROUP  BY t1.employeeid
        ORDER  BY total_skills DESC) AS dt
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0,
                          @prev_count := -1) AS user_init_vars
```